# How to use Ftfy

Tags: python, encoding

I have a xx.sql that has some encoding issues.
eg:

```
representâ€ in Xhosa)Â
```

I was advised to use [ftfy to fix]  (https://pypi.org/project/ftfy/)
I have installed `pip install ftfy` but for the sake of me cannot comprehend how to use it for example:

in terminal these are the commands i run :

```
python 
import ftfy
ftfy --output=xx.clean.sql xx.orig.sql (not sure how to point to the location of xx.orig.sql)
```

---

I feel like it is something simple that i am missing any help with this would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

These are directions for Ubuntu 18.04 that i used for my solution.

```
apt install python3
apt install python-pip3
pip3 install ftfy

cd /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ftfy
vim +100 cli.py
```

Changes to file bold part

```
if args.preserve_entities:
    unescape_html = False
else:
    unescape_html = 'auto'

config = TextFixerConfig(
    unescape_html=unescape_html,
    normalization=normalization**,**
    **uncurl_quotes=False**
)

try:
    for line in fix_file(
        file,
        encoding=encoding,
        config=config
```

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages#  ftfy --output=client.clean.sql xxx.sql
#copied the file to same directory
```

Comment: Is this an answer to your own question, or should it have been an edit to the question ?